# Register & Login password hashing method the same but not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, hash, pdo

I saw similar questions here but I don't think the answers apply to me, I'm sorry if they do..

Heres a sniplet of the code containing both procedures:

NOTE: *The login and register works perfectly fine without the hashing element.*

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $username = strtolower($username);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $salt = hash('md5', "$username");
    $password = hash('sha256', "$password"."$salt");

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `1_users` WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
        // Match
        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['id'] = $results['id'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['ip'] = hash('sha1', "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");
        header ("location: account.php");
    }
    else {
        $error = 'Invalid username/password!';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    // check for all fields..
    if ((empty($_POST['r_username'])) || (empty($_POST['r_password'])) || (empty($_POST['re_password'])) || (empty($_POST['email']))) {
        $r_error = 'One of the fields was empty.';
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `1_members` WHERE `username`=? LIMIT 1");
    $username = strtolower($_POST['r_username']);
    $username = trim($username);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($row) {
        $r_error = 'that username is already in use';
    }
    else if (($_POST['r_password']) !== ($_POST['re_password'])) {
        $r_error = 'The passwords did not match.';
    }
    else if (strlen($_POST['r_username']) <= '3') {
        $r_error = 'username too short - needs to be 4 more charicters.';
    }
    else if (strlen($_POST['r_password']) <='5'){
        $r_error = 'password not long enough, please make it 6-255 charicters or more.';
    }
    else {
        // woohoo lets make the account 
        $password = trim($_POST['r_password']);
        $salt = hash('md5', "$username");
        $password = hash('sha256', "$password"."$salt");
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);

       $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `1_members` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES(?,?,?)");
       $stmt->bindValue(1,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindValue(2,$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindValue(3,$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->execute();
       $_SESSION['id'] = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
       $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
       $_SESSION['ip'] = hash('sha1', "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");

       if ($_SESSION['active_cart']) {
           header ("location: cart.php");
       }
       else {
           header ("location: account.php");
       }
    }
}
```

Before adding the hashing to the passwords, it functioned as normal, im unsure on what my problem is.

Debugging:

`username: admin1`
`password: admin1`

---

Login procedure turns password to: `927364bb72cee168bd52c45a5d131b5923e2926eb6e8f0f46d6d7e5765cc3401`

Register procedure creates password as:
`927364bb72cee168bd52c45a5d131b5923e2926eb6e8f0f46d6d7e5765cc3401`

They match so what has gone wrong?

Also if i've got the wrong idea here or if im overlooking important security steps could you please advise on better methods.

Also, I'm not so worried about email validation and i'm fully aware there is lots of premade snipplets available for validating email and I will be getting to that at a later date.

Any CC is more than welcome.

EDIT: *The script returns "invalid username/password combo".*

Comment: Any specific reason you aren't using [`password_hash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)?

Comment: @SecondRikudo I was unaware of it, what makes it more special than hash?

Comment: It uses bcrypt and is more secure. It's also infinitely easier to use (it generates the salt for you, and has another function `password_verify()` to verify passwords painlessly)

Comment: So if I remove the hash and salt method and replace with `$password = password_hash('$password');` for the register, and `$password = password_verify('$password');` for the login it will work? or have I got the wrong idea?

Comment: Not sure if that would solve your problem (although it might, take note that you need PHP 5.5 or higher). It will however make your code much simpler and easier to read and debug.

Comment: The server has php 5.3 native, although it has up until 5.6, Im running 5.5. Which should I be running? and I can't figure out that it seems crazy, surely if i password_hash the password then i'd have to do it the same in both registration and login?

Comment: 5.6 is still in beta. 5.5 is latest stable and you should use that. Also, yes, if you use password_hash you'll need to use it anywhere there's a password needing to be hashed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/)

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your database field for the hashed password is too small, the field must be able to store 64 characters.

Even if you can solve this problem, you have an unsafe scheme to store passwords (SHA256 is ways too fast for hashing passwords). Have a look at the PHP function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it will generate a BCrypt hash and takes care of the generation of a safe salt. The salt will be part of the resulting 62 character string, so there is no need to store the salt separately. There exist also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for older PHP versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

This also means that you cannot verify the password directly within the SQL statement, instead read the hash from the database (by username), then call password_verify() with this hash.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that PDOStatement::rowCount() will not return "1" while executed on a SELECT-query. Take a look here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

(Especially Example #2)